# NVM is Access Denied

Tags: angular, npm, redux, npm-install, nvm

I have been using nvm to manage multiple node version. but it stopped working after trying to install a wrong dependency on Angular 5 app. I was trying to install ng-redux instead of ng2-redux.

I am unable to figure out the issue.

Error:

```
nvm ls
Program 'nvm.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ nvm ls
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ nvm ls
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: nvm.exe? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. nvm.exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Denied issue with NVM in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563188/access-denied-issue-with-nvm-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed after reinstalling nvm-setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and tried multiple solutions but the only one that did work was:

**Just open your Editor in Admin mode OR Run as Administrator.**