# Access Denied issue with NVM in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm getting 'access is denied' when I'm using nvm -v command in windows 10.
I have got the similar issue here 
[NVM is Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762782/nvm-is-access-denied)

But he himself gave a solution which is not working for me.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you only have to run it as administrator

Comment: I don't want to run it as admin

Comment: A lot of answers amount to "run as admin". A / the point of nvm is to run a node env / swap node envs without being admin. The answer to this question is https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues#permissions-exit-1-exit-5-access-denied . Just tell nvm to place nodjs versions it installs somewhere OTHER than under "Program Files". You can change this by just re-running the installer (and open new shell). A comment because there are so many upvotes on answers that are "just run as admin" that nobody will ever see the ones that avoid doing that (unless YOU upvote one too).

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and solved it as follows:

1. Uninstall "NVM for Windows 1.1.7"
2. Run the installer `nvm-setup.exe` as Administrator
3. Open an elevated Command Prompt (with Administrator privileges) and run

- `nvm install 8.12.0`
- `nvm use 8.12.0`

Now running `node -v` in a non-elevated Command Prompt works without issue.

Comment: It didn't helped me :( anyone else has a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly I don't have Admin access

Comment: For me all I had to do was `nvm use latest` at an elevated prompt.

Comment: FYI, this didn't work for me using Powershell as Administrator. I had to use Command prompt.

Comment: Pay attention to the second step, the administrator must be used the way open NVM installation package

Comment: NVM must not be installed as Administrator, otherwise the user won't be able to manage it.

Comment: It can be fixed by running the terminal used as Administrator, For instance run your git bash as adminstrator and then `npm use x.x.x`,  wil produce `Now using node v xx.x.x (xx-bit)`.

Comment: I didn't need to reinstall. I just opened terminal as an administrator.

Comment: For me the same, only the nvm use needs to be run with administrator privileges

Comment: For me the problem was using "Program Files" for the nodejs directory during installation.  I changed it to C:\Resources\nodejs. Daniel McMullen's answer below helped me find the [wiki explanation](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues#permissions-exit-1-exit-5-access-denied) for the fix.

Comment: Works for next LTS `18.7.0` as well

Comment: For me it works when I run the CMD as Administrator, but I had problems when run the VS code's terminal. What fixed my problem is:
1. Right click the shortcut of the VS code
2. Go to properties
3. Compatibility tab
4. Check "Run this program as an administrator"
5. Save

Answer (score 150):

Not like the other comments, you don't have to run the installer `nvm-setup.exe` as `Administrator`. Just install it like a normal software.

Make sure that when you run `nvm use xxx`, you run it in `Command Prompt` with `Administrator` privilege.

Comment: Your Windows setup may be configured so that you have to install packages as administrator.

Comment: Running the cmd, or the windows terminal with an open cmd tab in it (in my case), as administrator solved it :) thanks

Comment: There's also no need to run anything as Administrator when NVM is installed correctly, as it defeats the purpose of being able to manage the local environments independently.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is a relatively old post and I believe most people landing here are trying to solve the access denied feature introduced with nvm 1.1.8 - I hope this is helpful to those folks.

This is covered in the repos wiki [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues#permissions-exit-1-exit-5-access-denied)

If you have access to enable developer mode on your machine - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)

You can enable developer mode and then when installing nvm for windows choose an install directory outside of the protected "Program Files" folder for nvm and nodejs.

I went with c:\Programs\nvm and c:\Programs\nodejs respectively, but you could also use APP_DATA as the base for both, or as suggested in the wiki 'nvm4w'.

I'm now able to use the latest nvm and run 'nvm use x.x.x' inside of VS Code.

Comment: Great answer. This avoids the need to "run as Administrator" and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: After 10 months, I encountered this problem again, and then solved the problem through this answer!

When installing nvm-setup.exe, the default path of Symlink "C:\ Program Files\ nodejs" should be changed to "C:\ nodejs", and the installation is complete and the system can be restarted, so that it can be used normally without administrator permission!

Comment: thanks this is the only solution that worked for me in git bash, installing and running as normal user no admin

Answer (score 25):

1. Install nvm-setup.exe as Administrator
2. **open cmd.exe** as Administrator
3. nvm install 14.17.6
4. nvm use 14.17.6

Comment: I could install normally, but to change versions I needed to open in admin mode

Comment: running command line as an administrator helped me and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 22):

1. -->*Press* **window key + x**.
2. -->*Windows **PowerShell(Admin)***
3. -->*Now use **nvm** normally, you won't get any error.*

Comment: step 1 doesnt work on Win 11 FYI

Answer (score 18):

1. Execute terminal as admin
2. Access the folder from terminal
3. Use the same command for nvm, ex.: `nvm use 14.19.1`

Answer (score 16):

My problem occurs on, particularly, Visual Studio Code.

The solution for my case is to run Visual Studio Code as an Administrator.

To run Visual Studio Code as an Administrator on Windows 11, search for Visual Studio from the Windows search bar, then right-click on the app of Visual Studio Code and select "Run as administrator".

[image: Visual Studio Code, Windows 11 search]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: or hold down ctrl-shift when you open it

Answer (score 10):

For me, I didn't wanted to run cmd with administrator rights every time I needed to change node version so what I did was go to NVM installation folder on windows is located at `C:\Users\<username>\appdata\Roaming\nvm` and modified the `Properties>Compatibility` to Run as adminstrator and now when I run nvm on my not-running-as-administrator-cmd it will just prompt me to confirm if execute as administrator.

Comment: My company installed BeyondTrust software to block running unknown software (a painful pain!). Was opening CMD as admin but NVM still was giving me the "exit status 1: Access is denied" Changing the run as admin in the NVM executable solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This lets me have a prompt to elevate permissions for nvm but I only need it for `nvm use` and all other commands stopped showing their outputs. They worked again when I removed the prompt

Answer (score 6):

> "Elevation" refers "Windows Access Rights" by which Windows controls
> what you can do on the file, specifically what folders you can read
> and write to. You get them by using "Run As Administrator".

#### Enable Developer Mode

**Settings** -> **Update & Security** -> **For Developers** -> **Activate Developer
Mode**

At this point, you will be able to use nvm without elevation.

#### Elevate nvm executable on demand

**nvm root directory** -> **nvm.exe properties** -> **compatibility** -> **run this program as administrator** -> **apply**

Whenever you need to use nvm, you will be prompted to grant elevation.

#### Run elevated command prompt

Press **Windows + R**, type **cmd** into the box and then press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**.

#### Side note

I am not sure about this but I think you can use **nvm 1.1.6** release without all that hassle.

Comment: Bringing up a sudo Power Shell always works. I just want to not keep doing that. Those settings didn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with version 1.1.9, so no it's not fixed.

Answer (score 6):

1. **Open command prompt**
2. Right click on command prompt item in toolbar
3. then again right click on command prompt
4. click on **run as administrator**
5. then run nvm use `VersionNumber`
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

For those using nvm v1.1.8 in Windows, I tried to install nvm and open it in cmd as an administrator., it didn't help.

Try using nvm v1.1.7. It worked for me :)

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.7/nvm-setup.zip

Answer (score 4):

i have run command as a administrator
it works

```
run cmd as administrator
```

and then after
enter

```
nvm use 8.12.0/or your version which you desired to use
```

then it will work

Answer (score 4):

## [2022 UPDATE]

I came across this problem multiple times. Trying to run it as administrator, but then get an Error 145, or struggling because my integrated terminal in VSCode is not running as administrator by default...

Here is an Easy fix, recommanded by the NVM Windows team in the [Common Issues](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues#permissions-exit-1-exit-5-access-denied-exit-145) Page.

1- Create a folder at the root of your disk called "nvm4w" : `C:/nvm4w`

2- Go back to your `nvm-setup.exe` and run it (if you lost it, then go back to the NVM-Windows Releases and download the latest `nvm-setup.zip` file.

3- Then, when the installer ask you to "Select the folder in wich Setup should create the sumlink", select that "nvm4w" folder you just created.

After this, everything will be fine, the administrator privileges are not required anymore.

Comment: This did not work for me. The right-click on cmd -  'Run as administrator' did though.

Comment: This did not work for me either. If you read the [Common Issues](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues#permissions-exit-1-exit-5-access-denied-exit-145) page, the very first solution says "The most common permission issue has to do with creating symlinks. NVM4W uses symlinks (mklink is used in nvm use) to redirect the Node installation path to the appropriate installation. _Windows requires elevated administrative privileges to create symlinks_, but developer mode eases these restrictions." ...I did not want to turn on developer mode, I simply ran the console as admin.

Comment: This should be the valid answer. Having to run as administrator should not be the default option and not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

none of the admin cmd run-s described above solved access denied issue. However I reinstalled nvm in a C:\NVM\nvm and made the nodejs folder to be C:\NVM\nodejs and it worked without any access elevation.

thanks @Daniel McMullen for the link to Wiki

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.1.9 of NVM for Windows has an issue that causes this problem. The solution is to remove it and then install version 1.1.7 (without Administrator privileges) and then it should work just fine.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10. I didn't want to use administrator privileges. I just downgraded from 1.1.9 to 1.1.7 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this issue is to run the `sfc /scannow` command in the Command Prompt with administrative privileges. The SFC (System File Checker) command checks for corrupted system files and repairs them if necessary. Here's how to do it:

- Open the Command Prompt as an administrator. To do this, right-click
  on the Start menu and select **Command Prompt (Admin)**
- Type the following command and press Enter: `sfc /scannow`
- Wait for the scan to complete, which can take some time. If any corrupted files are found, the SFC command will automatically repair them.
- Restart your computer and try installing NVM again.
  **Note** that this solution may not work for everyone, as the underlying cause of the error can vary. If the problem persists, there may be other steps that you can take, such as checking your antivirus software settings or performing a clean boot of your system.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue. I wanted to install nvm s I deleted node js folder in program files and then installed nvm but instead of command I installed node js from installer which cause this issue. To use nvm we must delete previous node js installed so I uninstalled node js and nvm from control panel and then followed the following steps:

1. Installed nvm
2. install node js using command 'nvm install v8.12.0'
3. nvm use 8.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled NodeJS and also nvm from the my computer. And then redownloaded the [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) and installed the NVM and then by using this command I installed the specific NodeJS version **npm install 16.x.x**.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed the node version I wanted, but couldn't set it with `nvm use [version]` in Powershell. This worked for me:

1. Download *scoop* and install *sudo* for Windows with it, using the instructions of the following [link](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045816254-How-to-sudo-on-Powershell-Windows-executor).
2. Run `sudo nvm use [version]`.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find solution to my problem here, hence posting answer to this old question to benefit others.

I had installed node outside nvm without admin priviledges. In that case, no matter if you install or run nvm using admin priviledges, `nvm use ____` will give access denied.

I uninstalled node manually, installed it from within nvm and then ran `nvm use` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded my version of nodejs by using the "nvm use..." command, since I found using nodejs v17 was causing my issue. When I set my (Windows 10) machine to use nodejs v16.14.0 the problem went away.
To downgrade versions, I did the following, because there can also be difficulty doing that:
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/674#issuecomment-1050369304

Answer (score 0):

*Be carefull with Dev mode on

-- About Access Denied --
In this case, try with you Git Bash.
Search your Git Bash > Open File Location > Right Click > Open Properties > Compatibility and check Run as Adminsitrator.
Open Git Bash anywhere, type:
nvm install version
nvm list
nvm use yourversion (ex. 17.99.99)

-- About NVM -v --
The command is:
nvm version

I hope this solve your problem and others.

Answer (score 0):

It could be proxy issue. You can set the proxy url that npm already uses.

This is how you can find npm proxy config:

```
npm config list
```

Then set the same url for nvm:

```
nvm proxy "url"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run command prompt in administration**

1. install node version with nvm

   `nvm install <node_version>` (ex: nvm install 16.10.0)
2. use installed node version

   `nvm use <node_version>` (example:- nvm use 16.10.0)
3. check node version

   `nvm list <node_version>`

---

Or uninstall the previous nvm version and reinstall and do upper steps

Answer (score 0):

**Having nvm and want to use it in VSCode but getting those permission errors?**

1. Settings -> Update & Security -> For Developers -> Activate Developer Mode
2. re-install nvm into C:\nvm & C:\nodejs
3. Add to path, Search -> edit the system environment variables -> environment variables -> path -> add ->   `C:\nvm`. Repeat for `C:\nodejs`
4. restart vscode, now your integrated terminals has the nvm path & will always have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Node.js installed already, you need to **uninstall** it so it doesn’t lead to errors when using different versions of Node and installing packages from the NPM registry.

1. If you have Node.js installed already, uninstall it
2. Install nvm-setup.exe as Administrator
3. open cmd.exe as Administrator
4. nvm install node-version-number
5. nvm use node-version-number

[and finally, this article helped me much](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nvm-for-windows-how-to-download-and-install-node-version-manager-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Im on Windows 11. I had the same issue and it worked for me to open the console as an administrator, and then run the `nvm use lts` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any existing version of Node.js which was installed via Node's official installer, winget or Chocolatey, and then retry the command in your terminal as an Administrator.

> In my case, I had accidentally installed another version of Node.js using winget, which was causing conflict with NVM.

Answer (score -2):

It Solve my issue in windows

- Remove node completely.
- Install NVM
- Open CMD as administrator
- Install node specific version
- switch on that version(nvm use yourversion)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*